# Fail to precompile RCall package after installation

Tags: julia

```
julia> using RCall
[ Info: Precompiling RCall [6f49c342-dc21-5d91-9882-a32aef131414]
ERROR: LoadError: RCall not properly installed. Please run Pkg.build("RCall")
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] top-level scope at C:\Users\nicho\.julia\packages\RCall\eRsxl\src\RCall.jl:36
 [3] include(::Function, ::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:380
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:368
 [5] top-level scope at none:2
 [6] eval at .\boot.jl:331 [inlined]
 [7] eval(::Expr) at .\client.jl:467
 [8] top-level scope at .\none:3
in expression starting at C:\Users\nicho\.julia\packages\RCall\eRsxl\src\RCall.jl:33
ERROR: Failed to precompile RCall [6f49c342-dc21-5d91-9882-a32aef131414] to C:\Users\nicho\.julia\compiled\v1.5\RCall\8GFyb_RACSn.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at .\error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1305
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:1030
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at .\loading.jl:928
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:923
```

Set the "R_HOME" environment variable and package installed, but precompiling didn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build `RCall` after setting the `R_HOME` not just recompile it. Please also note that `R_HOME` should point to a R installation location rather than the executable.

Hence, the correct commands could look like this:

```
ENV["R_HOME"]="/your/R/installation/directory/path"
using Pkg
Pkg.build("RCall")
using RCall
```

Comment: In particular, `R RHOME` will use `R` in your path to have it show its `RHOME` directory which is, as noted here, the _top-level_ of its installation and not the path to the front-end script or binary or ...  That works the same way on all operating systems but Windows is as we know a little special for lack of a general `$PATH`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I have a followed-up question. Why do I need to build RCall before using it while for other packages I never did the "build" step?

Comment: You always do the build step - it is done when the package gets installed. See the "Building packages" section at https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1.5/managing-packages/  For some of packages when the configuration changes you need to build them again - another example could be PyCall